# Expected "(" before AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, camera

When I try to build my application XCode shows me this error

***Expected "(" before AVCaptureSession***

Can someone help me fixing this warning? Here's my code:

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
}

- (IBAction)SwitchON_Flash;
- (void)setTorchSession:(AVCaptureSession *)CaptureSession;

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

UIAlertView *NoFlash;

- (IBAction)SwitchON_Flash
{
    AVCaptureDevice *Device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    if ([Device hasTorch] && [Device hasFlash])
    {
        if (Device.torchMode == AVCaptureTorchModeOff)
        {
            AVCaptureDevice *Device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
            AVCaptureDeviceInput *FlashInput = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error: nil];
            AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *VideoOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
            AVCaptureSession *CaptureSession = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
            [CaptureSession beginConfiguration];
            [CaptureSession addInput:FlashInput];
            [CaptureSession addOutput:VideoOutput];
            [CaptureSession commitConfiguration];
            [CaptureSession startRunning];
            [Device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            [Device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            [Device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
            [Device unlockForConfiguration];
            [self setTorchSession:CaptureSession];
            [CaptureSession release];
            [VideoOutput release];
        }

        else
        {
            [torchSession stopRunning];
        }

    }

    else
    {
        NoFlash = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Uh-Oh"
                                             message:@"Your device doesn't have a flash camera"
                                            delegate:nil
                                   cancelButtonTitle:@"mhmm, OK"
                                   otherButtonTitles:nil];
        NoFlash.delegate = self;
        [NoFlash show];
        [NoFlash release];          
    }   
    }

- (void)setTorchSession:(AVCaptureSession *)CaptureSession <== /// ERROR HERE ///
{
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewController` does not have that method by default. You don't have the implementation of that method, hence it's giving you this warning. If you will try to run this code - you will get "unknown selector sent to instance" error.

You either have to add property for `torchSession` in view controller or implement that specific method.

Comment: add an instance variable, `@property` and `@synthesize` preprocessor directive for your `ViewController` class or implement the `setTorchSession:` method for it.

Answer (score 1):

The first answer is not necessarily right as you may have implemented the method but simply not declared it in your header file.

On the line where you get the warning, you are sending a message to self (in this case your view controller) to run the method setTorchSession with the parameter CaptureSession

Provided you have implemented the setTorchSessin method in your .m file, all you have to do is declare it in your interface (.h file) by adding the following line under your SwitchON_Flash method:

```
- (IBAction)SwitchON_Flash;
- (void)setTorchSession:(AVCaptureDeviceSession*)captureSession;
```

If you haven't got the method in your implementation file your App will crash with a "Unrecognised selector sent to instance" message.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rog I'll try that in a minute ^^,

Comment: Thanks but now XCode says Expected "(" before AVCaptureDeviceSession

Comment: Where in the code is this happening? Can you please paste your implementation of setTorchSession?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the class is AVCaptureDeviceSession ? I can't find it in XCode help at all.

Maybe you meant AVCaptureSession

Comment: You're right! :O but XCode keep saying: Expected "(" before AVCaptureSession

Comment: I did copy your code to a new project and it compiles without any warning or error after I commented out the [torchSession stopRunning] because touchSession is not defined anywhere.